# Change SI font in equation

Tags: fonts, siunitx

Right now I have SI defined so:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer, 
  group-minimum-digits = 4,
  detect-display-math = true,
  detect-weight,
  detect-mode = true,
  group-separator = {,}
}
```

My numbers are serif whereas I use Arial, which is a san serif font. Is it possible to make SI generate serif only when in equation mode?

sample equation:

```
\begin{subequations}
\label{eqn:decanterholdup}
  \begin{align}
    T & = 0.1\frac{\mu}{S_H - S_L} \\
     & = 0.1 \frac{0.856551}{0.999492 - 0.88435} \nonumber\\
     & = \SI{0.7439}{\hour}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

text font:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer, 
  group-minimum-digits = 4,
  detect-display-math = true,
  detect-weight,
  detect-mode = true,
  group-separator = {,}
}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


This is san serif. In the equation it is serif.

\begin{subequations}
\label{eqn:decanterholdup}
  \begin{align}
    T & = 0.1\frac{\mu}{S_H - S_L} \\
     & = 0.1 \frac{0.856551}{0.999492 - 0.88435} \nonumber\\
     & = \SI{0.7439}{\hour}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

This text is san serif. \SI{5}{\cm}
\end{document}
```

The numbers in the math environment are serif fonts but the last line with SI is san serif. How can I make that last line in the math environment serif?

Comment: Please provide an MWE, a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm afraid the sentence "My numbers are serif whereas I use Arial" makes no sense at all. Please clarify (a) what your document does at present and (b) what you would like it to do.

Comment: I've added a MWE, please take a look again.

Comment: The statement, "My numbers are serif" is still quite puzzling: It's *not* just the numbers, it's *everything* in math mode that's typeset using the (math) Roman font. Why do you appear to focus on the numerals? Please clarify.

Comment: in \SI the numbers are san serif. I want to make them serif.